# Database not linking with the php due to privilege issues

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication

I have a registration php file which is linked with a database  I created in a user I created in phpmyadmin. But the issue is whenever I submit values into it the database is not being updated. I don't know what is the issue also I am beginner in this area so I m not fully aware of the functionalities. Links to some images are below. Just go through them you will get a better idea of my query

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZtiRxPpTT3NNCut345TSjXOAkIsVsZkK/view?usp=drivesdk

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FZOEBq641DpmNWXeC3_LYy_FTK49Hm87/view?usp=drivesdk

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PHbKSPVTnJvvJ-1vWVQwga61JDlpxBIK/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/  Then please [edit] your question. You haven't given us enough information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code. Also, you are showing the success message even though you don't know if the query was executed with success.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
  $number = $_POST['number'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  if(empty($number))
  {
  $errornumber = "Number empty !";
  }
  elseif(empty($name))
  {
  $errorname = "Name empty !";
  }
  else {
  $query = "INSERT INTO `student` (`number`,`name`) VALUES('$number','$name')";
        if (mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
          $success = '<div class="alert alert-success col-lg-6 col-lg-push-3">
                      Registration successfully. You will receive an email when your account is approved.
                      </div>'
        }
  }
}
```

Now, all you have to do is use ,  and  where you want them to show.

if this doesn't work, it means you have other issues, posting images with portions of code is never a good option to go about asking for help. Nobody will steal your code.